# windows server 2008 certificate authority - issued cert valid from field

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate

When does new certificate's valid from field always date a few minutes in past?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that was the time on your CA's clock at the time it was issued.

Comment: nope, I have CA set to autoissue and I install cert as soon as I can, everything altogether doesn't take more than a minute, but 'valid from' is 10 minutes int the past.